# How can I solve this issue: Problems validating assets fields in app.json. I am using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Every time my react native app starts up, this error below keeps emerging:

`Error: Problems validating asset fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/ • Field: android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - image should be square, but the file at './assets/logo.png' has dimensions 1420x412.`

Can someone please help to resize the image to the specified dimensions? The sites and methods I have tried out aren't helping with this issue.

I tried to use PowerPoint, but there was no help with the aforementioned.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that the image specified in the android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage field of your app.json file should be square, but the image at ./assets/logo.png has dimensions of 1420x412, which is not square.

To fix this error, you need to replace the ./assets/logo.png image with a new image that has equal width and height dimensions.

Somewhere on the app.json you have something like this:

```
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png"
```

Once you have a square image, you can update the android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage field to point to the new image. (Or save the new image with the same name logo.png)

To edit your image you have many [free options](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20online%20image%20editor&rlz=1C1UEAD_esES1042ES1042&sxsrf=APwXEdc_e-2mYDLxNmIYAhPCihYJ-2P_ig%3A1679899741177&ei=XTwhZKy8CpqNgQaksIDwCA&ved=0ahUKEwjs3tKawvv9AhWaRsAKHSQYAI4Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=free%20online%20image%20editor&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQigUQsAMQQzIVCC4QigUQxwEQ0QMQyAMQsAMQQxgBMhUILhCKBRDHARDRAxDIAxCwAxBDGAEyDwguEIoFEMgDELADEEMYAUoECEEYAFAAWABg-wxoAnABeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQzAAQHaAQQIARgI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)